# Android 3g connection delay

Tags: java, android

I'll appreciate your help with the following:

**Question:**
I'm looking to rush the 3g connection and make it connect immediately.

**Explanation:**
I built an app (for Android), using HttpClient for connecting to my server, and Amazon's AWS API to connect to various Amazon services.

I noticed that occasionally, the connection establishment in 3g takes a lot of time, and it actually seems that Android just waits a while before sending the GET/POST/whatever request, and not even trying until then.

**Few Clarifications:**

- the 3g connection IS working (good signal) and the problem is with 3g ONLY.
- when trying to connect to the internet using a browser (e.g Boat Browser), the connection seems to "wake up" and those green&orange arrows at the status bar start lighting again. And..the browser works. Sometimes my request get "awakened" then as well.
- My requests DO work, but usually it takes a while (at least 1 minute) until they actually initiate.

I can put some code if needed, but it looks like it isn't related to what I do, it's just how Android works (maybe it's waiting for many requests before initiating 3g connection?), and that some apps (like Boat Browser) force the connection to send their request, or just refresh the 3g connection maybe.

**Thank you so much**

Comment: Ok I found one thing (maybe it'll be obvious).
If there is another AsyncTask (don't know about any other thread) running which is trying to use the connection, all other connection tasks will not start.

And that's why it "works" on WIFI. The response (or in my case "no response" / timeout) comes MUCH faster.
The current fix is to put a timeout to the connection (httpClient).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found enough information to clear this up!

The best thing to do with AsyncTasks as connection threads is to avoid them apparently,
And use Google Volley instead.

Please look at this link to understand the nuances concerning AsyncTasks:
http://www.jayway.com/2012/11/28/is-androids-asynctask-executing-tasks-serially-or-concurrently/
           (I found this link in a separate question but I can't find it, sorry).

And look at this link to understand what is Google Volley and how it's easier to implement a multi-threaded connection with it:
https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728

So..To **answer** the question:
1. On some/most cases, your AsyncTasks will NOT run concurrently.
2. In order to "force" a multi-threaded connection, use Volley (can be configured to run serially btw) or read the link above concerning AsyncTask to "enable" it.